# Can I avoid sending email to event attendees on o365 event creation?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

My app restores user calendar events using `POST` request to graph api `/calendars/{ID}/events`. In case user wants to restore event with attendees we usually don't want to send email invitation to them.

How can I achieve that using graph API?

If it is not possible via `graph API`, is there any other interface which allows to do that? I saw some docs on `EWS` XML based API and it seemed that where is an option for not sending email: `SendMeetingInvitations` but I can't find something similar in graph API docs or in MAPI properties list (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprops/f6ab1613-aefe-447d-a49c-18217230b148)

Once I had a look at some o365 backup solution and saw myself that it was able to restore event without sending emails. And it seemed to use graph API.

I have tried setting manually status of the attendee to `accepted` and all other possible types in event payload:

```
"attendees": [
        {
            "type": "required",
            "status": {
                "response": "accepted",
                "time": "2019-07-08T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "xxx",
                "address": "xxx@xxx"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: same situation here, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Please upvote the feature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/128774/disable-emails-to-attendees-when-creating-an-event.html). Or even better on [github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1549)